# How is the global variable being incremented when it's not being directly specified?

Tags: python, debugging, queue, circular-buffer

I'm working on a small project where I'm implementing a queue as a circular array. As a challenge, I was assigned to not use any list functions like append when implementing this ADT. It's assumed that I only need to resize the queue when it gets full. When I ran my code through a debugger and step through it, I find that the issue revolves around my self.read value (read pointer) which is the global variable in question. This is kind of perplexing to me since neither of my functions that would be affected increments my pointer. Could anyone shed some light on this problem for me?

This class is coded as:

```
class CircularQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, capacity=2):
        """
        Initialize the queue to be empty with a fixed capacity
        :param capacity: Initial size of the queue
        """
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.size = 0
        self.list = [0] * self.capacity
        self.sum = 0
        self.read = 0
        self.write = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.capacity == other.capacity 
               and self.size == other.size 
               and self.read == other.read 
               and self.write == other.write   

    def __str__(self):
        if self.size == 0:
            return "Queue is empty"

        content = ""
        while ((self.read + 1) % self.size) != self.write:

            content = content + str(self.list[self.read]) + " -> "
            self.read = (self.read + 1) % self.size
        content = content[:-3]
        return f"Contents: {content}"
    __repr__ = __str__
```

The portion that I'm interested in looking at is my enqueue and resize functions:

```
def resize(self):
    bigger = [None] * (self.capacity * 2) #create bigger queue
    b_ind = 0
    read_ptr = self.read
    while read_ptr != (self.write + 1): #iterate through old queue to copy into new queue
        bigger[b_ind] = self.list[read_ptr]
        b_ind += 1
        read_ptr += 1
    self.capacity *= 2 #setting capacity
    self.list = bigger #setting new list as queue
    self.read = 0 #normalize queue
    self.write = b_ind

def enqueue(self, number):

    if self.size == 0: #if queue was originally empty
        self.list[self.read] = number
        self.write += 1
    else:
        self.list[self.write] = number #add onto end of queue
        if ((self.write + 1) % self.capacity == self.read): #resize if queue loops back and the write pointer is the same as the read pointer
            self.resize()
        else:
            self.write = (self.write + 1) % self.capacity #set write pointer
    self.sum += number #add to sum
    self.size += 1  # increment size
```

This was the test case I ran for my code:

```
queue = CircularQueue()
queue.enqueue(23)
queue.enqueue(42)
queue.enqueue(2)
queue.enqueue(195)

print(queue)
```

Comment: In `__str__():` you have `self.read = (self.read + 1) % self.size`. So `self.read` gets updated. But updating the instance attributes in `__str__` seems like a rather bad idea....

Answer (score 1):

You mutate the state of your queue *when printing*. `print()` calls `__str__`, and that method alters your state:

```
self.read = (self.read + 1) % self.size
```

Use a local variable instead of `self.read`:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.size == 0:
        return "Queue is empty"

    content = ""
    read = self.read
    while (read % self.capacity) != self.write:
        if content:
            content += ' -> '
        content += str(self.list[read])
        read = (read + 1) % self.capacity
    return f"Contents: {content}"
```

Note the `while` loop condition; you want to see if the *current* read position is not the same as the `write` position (meaning you can display the current value), not the next position, and you want to wrap round at the *capacity*.

I adjusted your separator handling a little to only add the arrow in between values if at least one entry has been added to `content` already, that avoids having to remove a portion again.

Demo using the fixed `__str__` method (no other changes made):

```
>>> queue = CircularQueue()
>>> print(queue)
Queue is empty
>>> queue.enqueue(23)
>>> print(queue)
Contents: 23
>>> queue.enqueue(42)
>>> print(queue)
Contents: 23 -> 42
>>> queue.enqueue(2)
>>> print(queue)
Contents: 23 -> 42 -> 2
>>> queue.enqueue(195)
>>> print(queue)
Contents: 23 -> 42 -> 2 -> 195
```

Comment: If I'm not calling my or using the __str__ directly in my test cases, how is it updating?

Comment: @KevinLe: `print(queue)` will call the `__str__` method. If you *remove* your `__str__` method altogether, the problem also goes away. The problem also goes away when you are not echoing the queue (in the interactive intepreter) or printing it.